# PlaceHolder en el margen del input

Tags: css, bootstrap, material-design

¿Cómo se llama este efecto o propiedad? ¿Es de Bootstrap?:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, el placeHolder se alinea con el margen del TextBox al hacer click dentro de el para escribir.

Answer (score 14):

Son conocidos como 'Floating labels/placeholders'. Y están basados en [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout). Es un tipo de diseño con ciertos estándares creado por Google.

Hay varias maneras de poder realizarlo y eso varia de desarrollador a desarrollador, te dejo una manera. Solo faltaría meterle tus propios estilos.

```css
body{
 padding:50px;
} 
input[type="text"][required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="tel"][required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="password"][required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="email"][required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
form select[required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before
{
  color: #3399CC;
}

input[type="text"][required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="text"][required]:valid + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="tel"][required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="tel"][required]:valid + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="email"][required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="email"][required]:valid + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="password"][required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="password"][required]:valid + label[placeholder]:before,
form select[required]:focus + label[placeholder]:before,
form select[required]:valid + label[placeholder]:before
{
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -0.8em) scale(0.9, 0.9);
  transform: translate(0, -0.8em) scale(0.9, 0.9);
}
input[type="text"][required]:invalid + label[placeholder][alt]:before,
input[type="tel"][required]:invalid + label[placeholder][alt]:before,
input[type="password"][required]:invalid + label[placeholder][alt]:before,
input[type="email"][required]:invalid + label[placeholder][alt]:before,
form select[required]:invalid + label[placeholder][alt]:before
{
  content: attr(alt);
}
input[type="text"][required] + label[placeholder],
input[type="tel"][required] + label[placeholder],
input[type="password"][required] + label[placeholder],
input[type="email"][required] + label[placeholder],
form select[required] + label[placeholder] 
{
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin-top: calc(-1.5em - 2px);
  margin-bottom: calc((3em - 1em) + 2px);
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: normal;
}


input[type="text"][required] + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="password"][required] + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="tel"][required] + label[placeholder]:before,
input[type="email"][required] + label[placeholder]:before,
form select[required] + label[placeholder]:before
{
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0 6px;
  color: #9C9C9C;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #fff);
  background-size: 100% 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" required>
  <label placeholder="Ingresar NIP" for=""></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Muy interesante.